# Find JIRA tickets created between 9.00 am and 10.00 am

Tags: jira, jql

Assuming I have hours per day set at 8 and start time set at 9.00 am how can I narrow down tickets using a JQL filter for tickets created between 9.00 am and 10.00 am? I was thinking something like:

```
AND updated > startOfDay() AND updated < startOfDay("+1h")
```

Comment: Note I want to be able to apply this to a calendar widget for *all* days

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: [Filter issues updated by particular user in period of time using JQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828009/filter-issues-using-jql/30900714#30900714)

It seems like you are asking the same question. Hopefully this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

A scripted field using Script Runner plugin will show the hour:

```
import java.util.Calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.setTime(issue.created)
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).toString()
```