# Filter issues updated by particular user in period of time using JQL

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql

Is there any way to find all issues updated by particular user in particular time period in every day by using JQL or is there any plugin to solve this?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by updated you mean change of status you can chack something like this:

```
status changed by "user.name" and updated > startOfDay("-1")
```

Of course the start of the day -1 shows everything updated since yesterday, but you can also go with hours.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a query like this:

reporter = usernameGoesHere AND created > startOfDay() and created < "2015/06/18 15:00"

So I had one ticket that I created at 2:20. Running this query gave me all issues created from the start of today and then queried out the results that were created before 6/18 at 3:00PM

Let me know if this helps you out.

You can also look at the [Advanced Filtering page for JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACLOUD/Advanced+Searching)

Answer (score 1):

```
assignee = 'your user' AND updated > startOfDay()
```

You can create a filter which will update daily.